# How to pass cyrillic symbols with POST request with flask

Tags: json, post, flask, windows-1251

I have such a route:

```
@app.route('/wikidata/api/v1.0/ask', methods=['POST'])
def get_tasks():

    print(request.data)
    print(request.json)
    return jsonify(1)
```

I send a request:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d "{\"название\": \"значение?\",\"param1\": \"Q29424\"}" http://localhost:8529/wikidata/api/v1.0/ask
```

and get the error:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 223
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.5
Date: Fri, 15 Feb 2019 08:34:27 GMT

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Failed to decode JSON object: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 2: invalid continuation byte</p>
```

Meanwhile `print(request.data)` shows that `request.data` is `b'{"\xed\xe0\xe7\xe2\xe0\xed\xe8\xe5": "\xe7\xed\xe0\xf7\xe5\xed\xe8\xe5?","param1": "Q29424"}'`

The only thing that helped so far is

```
decoded_data = request.data.decode('windows-1251')
question = json.loads(decoded_data)
```

I'm looking a way to send a request properly (or configure server) so that I can use `request.json` without errors.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue today. The problem is, server does not recognize requests with cyrillic data. The solution was pretty easy: you need to encode cyrillic data:

```
import requests, json

cyrillic_data = '{"название": "значение?","param1": "Q29424"}'
encoded_data = json.dumps(json.loads(data), ensure_ascii=True)  # ensure_ascii is True by default so you can omit it
# {"\u043d\u0430\u0437\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435": "\u0437\u043d\u0430\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435?", "param1": "Q29424"}

requests.post("http://localhost:8529/wikidata/api/v1.0/ask", json=encoded_data)
```

Or, you can just encode your Python object like this:

```
json_object = {"название": "значение?","param1": "Q29424"}
json_text = json.dumps(json_object)

requests.post("http://localhost:8529/wikidata/api/v1.0/ask", json=json_text)
```

Answer (score -1):

That's a Windows specific issue likely due to the default charset in the Windows console prompt. The cyrillic characters in your command line are misinterpreted with a non UTF-8 compatible charset.

Since you already use Python, the easiest way IMHO to send your request is to use the `requests` module (that you can install using `pip install requests`). Then type this command in a python file, using UTF-8 as charset:

```
import requests
requests.post("http://localhost:8529/wikidata/api/v1.0/ask", json={"название": "значение?","param1": "Q29424"})
```

Run it and it will have the same effect as your curl command line, only with proper cyrillic characters handling.